# How to join mp3 and wav files using naudio to byte buffer c# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mp3, wav, naudio

I found a lot of articles about how to join mp3 or wav files,but i didn't find nothing about how to join audio files of different types.I want to play wav file then mp3 file,one after another.
I tried to convert wav file to mp3 by using.

```
  private static MemoryStream ConvertWavToMp3(string path)
    {

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                using (WaveFileReader rdr = new WaveFileReader(path))
                using (LameMP3FileWriter wtr = new LameMP3FileWriter(stream, rdr.WaveFormat, 320))
                {
                    rdr.CopyTo(wtr);
                    return stream;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I get bytes from mp3 file by following code.

```
 private static MemoryStream GetBytesFromMp3(string path)
    {
        string storageName = path.Substring(path.IndexOf("\\\\") + 2, path.IndexOf("\\", 3) - path.IndexOf("\\\\") - 2);
        string networkShare = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\\"));
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[storageName + "_User"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[storageName + "_Pass"]);

        using (new NetworkConnection(networkShare, credentials))
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (Mp3FileReader rdr = new Mp3FileReader(path,FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    byte[] result = new byte[rdr.Length];
                    rdr.Read(result, 0, result.Length);
                    int a = result.Max();
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(result);
                    return stream;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

and and then merge them 
by

```
  public static byte[] JoinFiles(List<FileWeb> files)
    {
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        int offset = 0;
        foreach (FileWeb file in files)
        {
            MemoryStream mp3Data;
            string fullPath = file.FilePath + "\\" + file.FileName;


            if (file.FileName.EndsWith("wav"))
            {
                mp3Data = ConvertWavToMp3(fullPath);

            }
            else
            {
                mp3Data = GetBytesFromMp3(fullPath);

            }


            if (mp3Data != null)
            {
                byte[] buffer = mp3Data.ToArray();
                output.Write(buffer, offset, buffer.Length - offset);
                offset = 4;
            }
        }
        return output.ToArray();
    }
```

But it didn't work.It plays only first part.If i use this code.

```
public static void Combine(string[] inputFiles, Stream output)
{
    foreach (string file in inputFiles)
    {
        Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(stream);
        if ((output.Position == 0) && (reader.Id3v2Tag != null))
        {
            output.Write(reader.Id3v2Tag.RawData, 0, reader.Id3v2Tag.RawData.Length);
        }
        Mp3Frame frame;
        while ((frame = reader.ReadNextFrame()) != null)
        {
            output.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

at `Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(stream)` i get error no mp3 header found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not convert anything to MP3. Just create appropriate reader for given file (`WaveFileReader`  for `wav` and `Mp3FileReader` for `mp3`). Both classes derives from `WaveStream` which provides `Read` method. Use that method to retrieve **uncompressed** data. Now you can easily merge two streams. Of course `WaveFormat` must match.

But you don't need to reinvent wheel. There is built in concatenation mechanism.

```
var wavReader = new WaveFileReader ("file.wav");
var mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader ("file.mp3");

// convert to different interface
var wavProvider = wavReader.ToSampleProvider ();
var mp3Provider = mp3Reader.ToSampleProvider ();

// Must all share the same sample rate and channel count
var merged = new ConcatenatingSampleProvider (new[] { wavProvider, mp3Provider });

var output = new WasapiOut ();

output.Init (merged);
output.Play ();

Console.ReadKey ();
```

Good luck.